# getJSON concurrency overwritting variables?

Tags: php, jquery, concurrency, getjson

I'm having a lot of trouble with my javascript page.

Basically, I have a html/javascript page that gets data from a php page. I'm doing this multiple times, pushing them into the array, and then displaying the array.

Here's a rundown of the code

```
    var spawnedNewspaper = [];
    var articlesToSpawn = null;

    $("#generate").click(function() {
        spawnNewspaper();
    });


    function spawnNewspaper(){

        if(itemsToSpawn==null){
            articlesToSpawn = 4;
            spawnedNewspaper = [];
        }

        if(itemsToSpawn > spawnedNewspaper.length)
            spawnAnItem();

        if(itemsToSpawn == spawnedNewspaper.length){
            itemsToSpawn = null;
            // ... display the results
        }
    }


    function spawnAnItem(nationalDexID, level, generateRandomBerry, generateRandomTMItem, generateRandomItem, knowsRandomTM, imageURL){
        $.getJSON("...url.../spawner_json.php?jsoncallback=?" , 
            {
                dataitename: data
            }
            , spawnAnArticlePart2
        );    
    }


    function  spawnAnArticlePart2(data){
        //returning from spawnAnItem callback
        p = ArticleObject(data.heading, data.date, data.author)

        spawnedNewspaper.push(p);
        spawnNewspaper();
    }


    function ArticleObject(heading, date, author){
        this.heading = heading;
        this.date = date;
        this.author = author;
        return this;
    }
```

So, after it's done, it shows my array with the correct number of articles, but each article is exactly the same when I know that it's generating unique things each time.

My thoughts are that there's a concurrency problem and things are being overwritten (I used push() so this is odd), or that there's a problem with my ArticleObject.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
p = ArticleObject(data.heading, data.date, data.author)
```

To use the `new` operator:

```
p = new ArticleObject(data.heading, data.date, data.author)
```

And then within your `ArticleObject()` function you don't need to say `return this;` because `this` will be returned automatically when the function is called with `new`.

What's happening is when you call the function with `new` JavaScript creates a new object that inherits from `ArticleObject.prototype` and within the function `this` points to that new instance. When you call the function without `new` JavaScript is setting `this` to `window` so each time your function runs it just updates the same properties on `window`.

For more information about using `new` read [what MDN has to say about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).